# How do I print an ag-Grid in Angular?

Tags: angular, printing, ag-grid

I am trying to print an ag-Grid in angular 6.
I follow the example given by ag-Grid.
The following function is causing me some problems.
My grid id is myGrid.

I get the following: error TS2339: Property 'style' does not exist on type 'Element'

```
function setPrinterFriendly(api) {
    var eGridDiv = document.querySelector('.myGrid');
    eGridDiv.style.height = '';
    api.setDomLayout('print');
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: did you check this TS2339: Property 'style' does not exist on type 'Element'? which style it is talking about can you share some more code?

Comment: I am using ag-Grid's standard example. https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-for-print/#example-for-print-complex.  I am now finding that its does not recognise setDomLayout.  My code is no different from that in the example.

Comment: can you recreate your first error in the plunkr? if we are not able to solve that then we can move on to HTMLElement solution and can fix that. link : https://plnkr.co/edit/50roGFvSYm57S9VV

Comment: I just read that setDomLayout is not available till V20.  I am still using V17.  So I guess this is my problem.

Comment: good. so now i guess you got to upgrade and it will be solved.

Comment: Hopefully ... although I do upgrades with a fair bit of trepidation .... lol.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
const eGridDiv = document.querySelector('.myGrid') as HTMLElement;
```

Reference: [HTMLElement.style | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style)

Comment: That seemed to work but unfortunately now it does not seem to know what setDomLayout  is.   Its says its an unresolved function or method.

Comment: Mark the answer as correct if it solved the posted question.